# Will removing a regressor from a model reduce the variance of the remaining regressor

Tags: multiple-regression, estimators, unbiased-estimator

Let's say our full model is a mean centered:

$$ y= B_0 + B_1(x_1-\bar x_1) + B_2(x_2-\bar x_2) + e$$

I know $B_0$ works out to be equal to $\bar{y}$, and so $SS_{Reg}(B_0) = 0$

My question is if we remove $x_2$ from the model, and use a new model does the variability of the estimator for $B_1$ always decrease from the full model? Or is only in the case that $x_2$ contributes to $y$?

Comment: Not all data is fit well by a linear model.  I think it is good to ask if the thing you are removing helps or harms the fit.  This is how I think about it: If $B_2$ was a random number that had no relationship to y, then in the perfect (unreal) case $B_2$ would be zero, but in practice it would be nonzero, and it reduces the signal to be extracted from x in informing y; so removing the term keeps the fit for $B_1$ from under-estimating uncertainty.  If $B_2$ was informative for y, and was removed, then overall error increases and the uncertainty in $B_1$ also is falsely increased.

Comment: so you're saying if the full model is the true model, removing $B_2$ will increase the variance of $B_1$, but if the reduced model is the true model, removing $B_2$ wouldn't change?

Comment: According to my textbook, "Deleting variables never increases the variances of the estimates of the remaining parameters." (introduction to linear regression analysis, Montgomery)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I initially thought about the problem:

If $B_2$ was a random number that had no relationship to y, then in the perfect (unreal) case $B_2$ would be zero, but in practice it would be nonzero, and it reduces the signal to be extracted from x in informing y; so removing the term keeps the fit for $B_1$ from under-estimating uncertainty. If $B_2$ was informative for y, and was removed, then overall error increases and the uncertainty in $B_1$ also is falsely increased.

Note: if you have too many parameters then it over-fits to the noise and the uncertainty gets small.  A hold-out set is a fair way to detect the presence of over-fitting.

Now I start by making a single-case test:

```
require(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse,
       pracma,
       reshape2)  

#x variable
set.seed(566)
x <- runif(100, min=-1, max=1)


#reproducible parameters
set.seed(659)
beta <- rnorm(n=3,mean=0,sd=1)

#make true y variable
y_true <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x + beta[3]* x^2

#add scaled noise 
eps <- runif(100, -0.5, 0.5)
y  <- y_true + eps

#prep to plot
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, y_true=y_true)
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = 1)

#plot it
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=value,  colour=variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_light() +
  scale_colour_discrete(name  ="Legend",
                        labels=c("True", "Noisy")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Legend",
                       labels=c("True", "Noisy"))


est1 <- lm(data=df, formula = 'y ~ 1 + x + I(x^2)')
s1   <- summary(est1)

est2 <- lm(data=df, formula = 'y ~ 1 + x')
s2   <- summary(est2)

print("Actual:")
print(beta)

print("Estimated on full model:")
print(s1$coefficients)

print("Estimated on full model:")
print(s2$coefficients)
```

It yields this figure:

[image]

Here are the text outputs:

```
> print("Actual:")
[1] "Actual:"

> print(beta)
[1] 0.5324600 0.9816669 1.0321112

> print("Estimated on full model:")
[1] "Estimated on full model:"

> print(s1$coefficients)
             Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.5119078 0.03778625 13.54746 4.250419e-24
x           0.9417088 0.04962689 18.97578 2.027009e-34
I(x^2)      1.0562187 0.08934154 11.82226 1.670556e-20

> print("Estimated on full model:")
[1] "Estimated on full model:"

> print(s2$coefficients)
             Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.8281143 0.04148706 19.96079 2.659613e-36
x           0.8148613 0.07531269 10.81971 2.031318e-18
```

So the full model has good estimates, the incomplete model has poor estimates for both parameters, and the uncertainty in the parameters in the incomplete model is higher than in the complete model.

I leave it to the reader to make a loop and repeat the process, without seeds, perhaps 1000 times, and look at how the variation in the parameter uncertainty differs between complete and incomplete models.

This is a trivially simple model, but standing on the canonical models behind things like the Bliss Beetle data might be a first step to extending this to more realistic models.